# How to changeJTable as editable and not in different selection?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

i just enter some details in JTable. and store those details in my database with specific id. But if i retrieve those details in my JTable based on id, on that time the JTable should not allow edit operation in it. it just for view purpose. How can i set whether Jtable is editable or not  based on user selection. (Insert, Search)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Editability is controlled, primarily, through the `isCellEditable` method of the `TableModel`.

You could establish a setting within your `TableModel` which can return `false` when you want the model to be read only.

See [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for more details

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at  and [TableModel.isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html#isCellEditable-int-int-).

You have to use a `TableModel` and override its `isCellEditable()` method in which you can tell which cells you want to allow editing based on the row and column indices.

Note: There is a [JTable.isCellEditable(int row, int column)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#isCellEditable-int-int-) too which calls the model's `isCellEditable()` method.

Comment: *"You have to override JTable.isCellEditable()"* - Oh dear lord no, there is never any need to do that.  Let the model control it, this way, you can switch models and have a non-editable and editable version...and it can be applied to any instance of `JTable` you want...

Comment: Well, I listed that as an option and not as the preferred way.

Comment: Well, consider this, this is professional forum. We should consider providing professional answers. It's not just not preferred, it's generally a bad idea on multiple levels.  We should "try", where possible, to lead people to not just the "right answer", but the correct method of implementation and workflow and use of the API, which would most commonly be used ...but, that's just me ;) - In 15 years, I've never found a need to override just about any methods within of `JTable` - usually set up a factory to customise settings, but that's about it ;)