# Make Jtable Noneditable without using setModel()

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I want to make my JTable Non-editable

As I use following code to set rows using SetModel():

```
jTable1.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs)); //Resultset is added as each row using r2xml JAR file
```

I cant use follwing code:

```
jTable1.setModel(new DefaultTableModel() {

    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
       return false;
    }
});
```

Because we cannot use two setModel() for jTable.

How to overcome this problem?
I want to setresult and make jTable Noneditable.

Comment: What you want to do with the values modified by the user? Store in a database directly? Hold the modifications transient in memory and store on commiting?

Comment: I want to make Jtable Noneditable after i fetch rows from DB using resultSettoTable(rs)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are 2 ways to achieve that:

1. Create and use your own `TableModel` implementation which forwards all calls to the table model returned by `DbUtils` except for `isCellEditable()` in which you can return always `false` hence disabling editing. Your own table model could get the model returned by `DbUtils` as a constructor argument for example.
2. You can extend `JTable` and override its `isCellEditable()` method to return `false` (by default it calls the model's `isCellEditable()` method). Maybe other Swing enthusiasts will see this as an evil hack, but it is the simplest solution to your problem here.

### Elaborating method #1

This is how you can create your model:

```
class MyModel implements TableModel {
    private final TableModel m;
    public MyModel(TableModel m) {
        this.m = m;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        // This is how we disable editing:
        return false;
    }

    // The rest of the methods just forward to the other model:

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return m.getRowCount();
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return m.getColumnCount();
    }

    // ...and all other methods which I omit here...
}
```

And this is how you can use it:

```
jTable1.setModel(new MyModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs)));
```

### Elaboration of method #2

Extending `JTable` can even be an anonymous class:

```
JTable jtable1 = new JTable() {
    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
        // This is how we disable editing:
        return false;
    }
};
```

And using it:

```
// You can set any model, the table will not be editable because we overrode
// JTable.isCellEditable() to return false therefore the model will not be asked
// if editable.

jTable1.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
```

Comment: if i use isCellEditable(),then how i can set it to jtable

Comment: Beacause i cannot use two setModel() for single jTable

Comment: First option will not work without to implement setValueAt method.

Comment: @user3360047 You only have to call `setModel()` once, with your custom model (which uses the model returned by `DbUtils`). I edited my answer to elaborate it.

Comment: @SergiyMedvynskyy The custom model would forward the `setValueAt()` call to the other model just like all other methods. I don't see a problem here.

Comment: @icza sorry i've missunderstold the question. thought that the autor want to make it editable from non-editable.

Comment: +1 for overriding the `isCellEditable(...)` of the table. `Maybe other Swing enthusiasts will see this as an evil hack,` why?. The JTable controls the `View`. In this case the view is not editable no matter which TableModel you use.

Comment: @camickr I was referring to MadProgrammer. I wrote this earlier in one of my other answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25659169/1705598) and he didn't like it. Read the comments below the linked answer, also you might want to see the edit history of that answer to see what caused all that. According to him _"let the model control it"_.

Comment: @icza when i use #method2 it gives error at table declaration i.e private javax.swing.JTable jTable1;//jTable1 already defined error

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code for make non editable jTable
simply you write one line in your program
jTable.disable();